# Is there any way to run a desktop automation console application on a machine when the user is logged out or the machine is in idle.?

Tags: c#

I am automating a desktop application using image recognition along with some click actions on the screen based on the image coordinate position. I need to run this application when the user is logged out. Automation fails when I use task scheduler. Is there any alternative to resolve this issue?

Comment: Task Scheduler already does that. In the `General` properties tab of a task you select whether the task should run whether the user is logged on or not

Comment: When the user is logged out there's no screen, coordinates or clicks. There's not even a desktop, only a lock screen. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Run as a service.

Comment: You can create windows service to do this and also is a better solution for background tasks. Don't forget set service privileges

Answer (score 0):

If the machines are suspended or idle you could create a windows service with a System.Timer:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsService1
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Timers.Timer m_mainTimer;
    private bool m_timerTaskSuccess;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //
            // Create and start a timer.
            //
            m_mainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            m_mainTimer.Interval = 60000;   // every one min
            m_mainTimer.Elapsed += m_mainTimer_Elapsed;
            m_mainTimer.AutoReset = false;  // makes it fire only once
            m_mainTimer.Start(); // Start

            m_timerTaskSuccess = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // omitted
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            // Service stopped. Also stop the timer.
            m_mainTimer.Stop();
            m_mainTimer.Dispose();
            m_mainTimer = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // omitted
        }
    }

    void m_mainTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // do some work

            m_timerTaskSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            m_timerTaskSuccess = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (m_timerTaskSuccess)
            {
                m_mainTimer.Start();
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

}